# Is there a way to make this print without a list inside a list?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I am writing a scheme program in dr racket that takes a list of numbers representing a matrix sets an item in the list to the number given. So far it works for case row 1 column 1 and knows where to place the number but any other case it makes lists of lists. I have attempted to make a function to help but still receive the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The error I'm getting:

> (setCell Matrix 2 2 9)
>   ((2 4 6 8) (1 (9 5 7)) (2 9 0 1))

I need

> (setCell Matrix 2 2 9)
>   ((2 4 6 8) (1 9 5 7) (2 9 0 1))

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(define Matrix '(( 2 4 6 8 )( 1 3 5 7)( 2 9 0 1)))

;getCell Matrix Row Column
;if i want row 2 col 2
(define (getCell Matrix Row Column)
  (if (= Row 1)
      (if (= Column 1)
          (car (car Matrix))
          (getCell (cons (cdr (car Matrix)) ()) Row (- Column 1))
       )
      (getCell (cdr Matrix) (- Row 1) Column)
  )
)
;> (getCell Matrix 1 1)
  ;2

;(define Matrix '(( 2 4 6 8 )( 1 3 5 7)( 2 9 0 1)))

;setCell Matrix Row Column Item
(define (setCell Matrix Row Column Item)
    (if (= Row 1)
          (if (= Column 1)
          (helpMe Matrix Item)
          (cons
           (cons (car (car Matrix))
                      (setCell (cons (cdr (car Matrix)) ()) Row (- Column 1) Item))
           (cdr Matrix))
       )
      (cons (car Matrix) (setCell (cdr Matrix) (- Row 1) Column Item))
  )
 )

 (define (helpMe Matrix Item)
      (cons (cons Item (cdr (car Matrix))) (cdr Matrix)))
  ;ERROR:
 ;>(setCell Matrix 2 2 9)
 ;((2 4 6 8) (1 (9 5 7)) (2 9 0 1))

 ;> (setCell Matrix 1 1 9)
 ;((9 4 6 8) (1 3 5 7) (2 9 0 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem.
The basic idea is coordinate, data structure shape, make a good abstraction, visting all element, given coordinate get corresponding value.

In here we define upper left element is (1,1) (so we have to minus 1)

First we want build a same matrix. Second each value determine by function f. And f input is coordinate (i,j) so f is a function call upgrade function. You can set any rule. Like a common question is ask you build diagonal matrix the rule will be i=j. (It a beautiful abstraction)

It's means we must make this coordinate

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) ...                        (0,(length (first m))
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)    ...                     (1,(length (first m))
(2,0 ...                                                          
...
(length of matrix),0)   ... ((length of matrix),(length (first m)))
```

Then we send coordinate to f. So we can let f return original value in input matrix but when i = row and j = column we return new value (item). The same idea you can build vector or orthers not just list. The same idea can use to build triangle circle or something else not just rectangle.

```
#lang racket

(define (setCell  m row column item)
  (local ((define index-i (- row 1))
          (define index-j (- column 1))
          (define (f i j)
            (if (and (= i index-i) (= j index-j))
                item
                (list-ref (list-ref m i) j))))
    (build-list (length m) (lambda (i) (build-list (length (first m)) (lambda (j) (f i j)))))))


;;; TEST
(define k  
  '((1 2 3)
    (1 2 3)
    (1 2 3)))

(setCell k 1 1 100)
(setCell k 2 3 100)

(define k2  
  '((1 2 3)
    (1 2 3)))

(setCell k2 1 3 100)
(setCell k2 2 3 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing a scheme program in dr racket that takes a list of numbers representing a matrix sets an item in the list to the number given.

```
#lang racket

(define matrix-id (build-list 4 (λ (x) (build-list 4 (λ (y) (if (= x y) 1 2))))))
;; => '((1 0 0 0) (0 1 0 0) (0 0 1 0) (0 0 0 1))

;; [X] Number Number X [List-of [Lis-of X]] -> [List-of [Lis-of X]]
(define (set-mat row col item mat)
  (for/list ([l mat] [i (length mat)])
    (for/list ([e l] [j (length l)])
      (if (and (= i row) (= j col))
          item
          e))))

(set-mat 1 1 'fef matrix-id)
;; => '((1 0 0 0) (0 fef 0 0) (0 0 1 0) (0 0 0 1))
```